# Biblatex using shorthands and numeric style - label sizes

Tags: biblatex, indentation, biber, subdividing

***Current situation:***
I'm required to cite "normative" documents (read: standards and manuals) separately from articles and books etc. Using `biblatex` and `biber` with the `numeric` style I'm doing that by issuing multiple `printbibliography` commands like so:

```
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
%... lots of stuff
\printbibliography[type=standard,title=Standards \& Manuals]
\vskip\baselineskip
\printbibliography[type=manual,heading=none]
\printbibliography[nottype=standard,nottype=manual]
```

which gives a heading **Standards & Manuals**, prints a list of manuals, leaves a bit of space then the list of standards and finally, under a new heading **Bibliography** gives books and articles etc. Thus far everything is fine, enter:

***The Problem:*** I'm using the `shorthand` field in my database for the standards and manuals which works perfect as far as output within the text is concerned and sets the shorthand as the label in the bibliography and prints the details to the right of it - problem is: my shorthands are considerably longer than the labels generated by the `numeric` style, but even though they're in three different `\printbibliography` commands, everything gets indented to the maximum width of the label, making the part for books and articles look quite ridiculous.

The following shows the problem with only two separate `\printbibliography` (and an obviously exaggeratedly long shorthand):
[image: output with problem]

Now  what I would obviously want is for each of the `\printbibliography` commands to only use the indentation actually necessary to accommodate the largest label appearing within, i.e. rendering the **Manuals** section as above, but the **Bibliography** section like follows:
[image: output bibliography correct]

Can anyone help me to achieve this? Or give me some pointer where to look?

The above was produced with the following MWE on an up-to-date TeXLive 2014:

```
\documentclass[10pt,british]{scrbook}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@manual{HowTo,
    title = {How to Make the World Go Round},
    shorthand = {HowToMakeTheWorlGoRound},
    publisher = {The Publisher},
    year = {2000}
}

@article{Article,
    author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B.},
    journal = {Journal Title},
    pages = {113--126},
    title = {The Article},
    volume = {65},
    year = {1900}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\let\cleardoublepage\relax
\chapter{The Document}
Nothing to see here, but we refer to the \parencite{HowTo} based on a principle discovered by \textcite{Article}.

\printbibliography[type=manual,title=Manuals]
\printbibliography[nottype=manual]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can see a similar effect in [Biblatex, Use of prefixnumber changes indentation of all subbibliographies](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129612/35864).

Comment: @moewe thanks a lot for the link - setting me on the right track for a solution;)

Comment: Fine! Could your solution also be applied to the question I linked to? If so, maybe you would like to answer it.

Comment: @moewe I'll have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @moewe's link and the comments in there I found a solution that seems to work and which allows setting the width of the label for the `numeric` part arbitrarily.

Defining a new `bibenvironment` with `\defbibenvironment{bibnumeric}...` and therein setting `\labelnumberwidth` allows adjusting the width of the label for any `\printbibliography` using that `bibenvironment` - by adding `env=bibnumeric` to the `\printbibliography` command.

Thus the above MWE can be fixed by adding:

```
%% make substyle for normal numbered bib
\defbibenvironment{bibnumeric}
    {\list
        {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
            \printfield{prefixnumber}%
            \printfield{labelnumber}}}
        {\settowidth{\labelnumberwidth}{8888}%
            \setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
            \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
            \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
            \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
            \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
            \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
        \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
    {\endlist}
    {\item}
```

which is a copy of the `\defbibenvironment{bibliography}` found in `numeric.bbx` of `biblatex`, apart from the added `\settowidth{\labelnumberwidth}{8888}` which allows setting the label width for the new `bibenvironment` arbitrarily - the value used allows for a three digit citation number.

The full MWE then is:

```
\documentclass[10pt,british]{scrbook}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@manual{HowTo,
    title = {How to Make the World Go Round},
    shorthand = {HowToMakeTheWorlGoRound},
    publisher = {The Publisher},
    year = {2000}
}

@article{Article,
    author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B.},
    journal = {Journal Title},
    pages = {113--126},
    title = {The Article},
    volume = {65},
    year = {1900}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

%% make substyle for normal numbered bib
\defbibenvironment{bibnumeric}
    {\list
        {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
            \printfield{prefixnumber}%
            \printfield{labelnumber}}}
        {\settowidth{\labelnumberwidth}{8888}%
            \setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
            \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
            \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
            \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
            \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
            \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
        \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
    {\endlist}
    {\item}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\let\cleardoublepage\relax
\chapter{The Document}
Nothing to see here, but we refer to the \parencite{HowTo} based on a principle discovered by \textcite{Article}.

\printbibliography[type=manual,title=Manuals]
\printbibliography[nottype=manual,env=bibnumeric]
\end{document}
```

giving the output:

[image: fixed output]

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in [Biblatex, Use of prefixnumber changes indentation of all subbibliographies](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129612/35864) `biblatex` 3.11 has the new option `locallabelwidth` which makes the labelwidth calculation local for each `\printbibliography`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,british]{scrbook}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@manual{HowTo,
    title = {How to Make the World Go Round},
    shorthand = {HowToMakeTheWorlGoRound},
    publisher = {The Publisher},
    year = {2000}
}

@article{Article,
    author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B.},
    journal = {Journal Title},
    pages = {113--126},
    title = {The Article},
    volume = {65},
    year = {1900}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber,locallabelwidth]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\let\cleardoublepage\relax
\chapter{The Document}
Nothing to see here, but we refer to the \parencite{HowTo} based on a principle discovered by \textcite{Article}.

\printbibliography[type=manual,title=Manuals]
\printbibliography[nottype=manual]
\end{document}
```

[image: Two bibliographies with different indentations each.]