# How to reset horizontal spacing between two calls to \printbibliography?

Tags: biblatex

Consider the following code:

```
\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
  @article{Key1,
    title = {First title},
    author = {First author},
    shorthand = {ShortHand},
    keywords = {shorthanded}
  }

  @article{Key2,
    title = {Second title},
    author = {Second author}
  }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}

My text cites both \cite{Key1} and \cite{Key2}.

\printbibliography[keyword=shorthanded]

\printbibliography[notkeyword=shorthanded]

\end{document}
```

Here I print two distinct bibliographies differentiating by keyword, and the first kind of entries happen to be referenced by shorthands (conference names).

As you can see from the output, the large spacing due to the shorthand in the first bibliography is retained when printing the second.

[image: output]

This appears nice in the MWE, but in my real document the two bibliographies are printed on separate pages anyway (separate chapters* in a `book` class), so the vertical alignment is not needed, and the wasted horizontal space in the second one is annoying and useless.

How can I reset the second call to `\printbibliography` so to independently reserve the right horizontal space for its entries?

Comment: With multibib package it would be like you want by default. Check this if you don't have too many references and it helps: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/457454/120578

Comment: Unfortunately I'm specifically using `biblatex` in many other ways so I need a solution working with it

Answer (score 2):

You can use `biblatex`'s option `locallabelwidth=true`.

I also suggest the use of `\printshorthands` instead of `\printbibliography[keyword=shorthanded]`. As a matter of fact, you could well forgo with the need to declare such a keyword altogether. See, for example, this [lockstep's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44436/105447), incorporated below.

```
\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
  @article{Key1,
    title = {First title},
    author = {First author},
    shorthand = {ShortHand},
  }

  @article{Key2,
    title = {Second title},
    author = {Second author}
  }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=numeric,locallabelwidth=true]{biblatex}

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44436/105447
\defbibcheck{noshorthand}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}{}{\skipentry}%
}

\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}

My text cites both \cite{Key1} and \cite{Key2}.

\printshorthands

\printbibliography[check=noshorthand]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I get an error `Package xkeyval Error: 'locallabelwidth' undefined in families 'blx@opt@pre'`. Do I have an outdated version of the `biblatex` package?

Comment: That might be the case, which version are you using? (current is 3.11).

Comment: That is indeed a recent inclusion. Revision history for biblatex shows us "Added `locallabelwidth` option" for version 3.11.

Comment: Do you think there might be a way to hack the same effects in older versions?

Comment: There usually is. `labelwidth` is among the inputs of `defbibenvironment`, so you might get a hook to intervene there. But, in this respect, two questions. Is there a reason for not updating? (I respect that, if there is, e.g. deadline approaching, overleaf, whatever). Second, how old? Which version are you acctually using?

Comment: Yes, the reason is the phd thesis deadline approaching in one hour and a half XD I do not know how to get the installed version of the package, honestly, but I'm running MacTeX 2017

Comment: That is a very good reason. See this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/198780/105447. Btw, would you say marking this as a duplicate of that one is ok? I would've done it before, but I just found it.

Comment: That is actually a workaround, imho. The trick lies in `\settowidth{\labelnumberwidth}{8888}` which you will have to set manually according to the number of digits your bibliography has. But it certainly gets the job done.

Comment: Great! Very good luck with your thesis then!

Comment: thanks.. not just for this answer, but I'll greet TeX.SE in the acknowledgements for sure ;)